# How to extract word from a sentence in Linux Shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell file with the below SQL statements in it:

```sql
SELECT distinct vpi.pin_id_e 
FROM MSSINT.V_DSLAMS vd,
MSSINT.v_pin_inventory_old vpi 
where vd.dslam like '%@%'
and vd.dslam_id = vpi.dslam_id ;

select pa.circuit_design_id,pa.node_address,c.exchange_carrier_circuit_id,c.type,c.rate_code,c.status 
from ASAP.port_address pa,
asap.circuit c
where pa.equipment_id = 4561233 and pa.circuit_design_id is not null
and pa.circuit_design_id = c.circuit_design_id;
```

In the above content of my shell file, I have to extract the table or view names alone (those between `from` and `where` keywords).

I have seen a lot of suggestions to get words based on position, but I don't want those since they will not work like between operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'toupper($0) ~ /^FROM/ { getline;flag=1 } toupper($0) ~ /^WHERE/ { flag=0 }flag' filename
```

With awk, convert the string to upper case and then pattern match against FROM at the beginning of the line. If this exists, read in the next line and set flag to one. When WHERE is encountered at the beginning of the line, set the flag equal to 0. The complete line will then only print when flag is set to one i.e. between the from and where lines